# footer stays fixed even with position set to absolute

Tags: html, css, footer

i am trying to design a simple footer that should be located at the bottom of the page. in other words, the user would need to scroll down to see it if the page is long. somehow the footer refuses to stay there and instead is always visible in the bottom of the browser window. i thought this would only happen if its position is set to fixed, not absolute. i am new to rails and on top of this, bootstrap is installed in the project by default. was thinking it would not be a problem since i don't use the default footer class. any ideas why this is happening?

in _footer.scss:

```
.footer-artcollabs {
  background-color: $grey-light-med;
  height: 72px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  p {
    margin: 0 30px 4px 30px;
  }
}

.foot-logo-container {
  margin-left: 30px;
  width: 44px;
  height: 42px;
}
```

in _footer.html.erb:

```
<div class="footer-artcollabs">

  <div class="foot-logo-container">
    <%= render 'shared/logo' %>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
```

This is sticking it to the bottom of the page.

https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp

Comment: this is exactly what is in my code (inside .footer-artcollabs)

Comment: That's the part that is incorrect remove it.

Comment: if i do this, the footer is not aligned to the bottom on a page that is shorter than the browser window

Comment: Without seeing the full code can't really comment

Comment: the full code will be different for each page that the footer is on. i am looking for a solution that will work for a page with a lot of content, as well as one with very little. the rest of the page is organized in divs (all with position relative, or default)

Comment: post a link to a page then so I can check. The key is to set a min-height to your main content above the footer then.